# Convert from Extjs 4.0.7 to Extjs 4.1

Tags: extjs4, extjs4.1

I have been developed one application in extjs 4.0.7. and now if i want to use extjs 4.1. for further implementation of that application.

Is it possible? Plz help me, if answer is yes.

Thank you

Comment: When I upgraded from 4.0.7, the only changes were removing a few hack for bug fixes in 4.0.7 - other than that, it all worked for me.

Comment: hi..Izhaki..thank you..but can you tell me that few hack something like? because i want to upgrade..so it will be big help for me..thanks

Comment: These were actually a js file that overridden some ExtJS classes to fix bugs in them - the point is that once upgraded to 4.1, I didn't need that script anymore. It's fairly easy to check if your system works: just rename `/extjs` to `/extjs-4.0.7`, then into `/extjs` put version 4.1 and see what happens.

Answer (score 3):

Of course an upgrade is possible. Replace your extjs scripts (ext-all.js etc) from 4.0.7 to 4.1. In most cases you should not face any problem as this is mostly a performance focussed release. http://www.sencha.com/blog/whats-new-in-ext-js-4-1

Comment: hi..harshal thank you so much..but there was one question in my mind that all my listeners and methods will be same..? Is it not possible that "xyz" listener is removed from new version(ext4.1) and that i used in old version (ext4.0.7)? If yes then will i not get so many errors?

Comment: That's what I am saying...download extjs-4.1, replace your existing extjs scripts - if you face any problem post-migration then try to solve that. You can't just speculate on possible problems without migration.

Answer (score 2):

Convert from [Extjs 4.0.7 to Extjs 4.1](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?198501-ExtJS-4.0.7-to-4.1.0-Conversion).

Answer (score 2):

Yes you can upgrade your application from extjs 4.0.7 to 4.1.1 For that you need to replace your `ext-all.js/ext-debug-all.js` (for debug purpose) but after replacing you may get few problems related to syntax such as in editor, previously we were using record, instead of that we need to use `e.record`.

```
listeners : {
  'edit' : function(editor, e) {
    var grid = e.grid;
    var record = e.record;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with the ext-all.css if you are using any custom images on the panel header. Be wary of it. And also html property in the panel is not working.